# Problems with Java applet

Tags: java, support

Please take a look at the following Java applet:

http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/po4.html

It is supposed to show some mathematical stuff with vertices and edges. The only thing I see is unfortunately one yellow dot.

What might be the reason for this?

Please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows with Sun Java 6 it works fine. In Ubuntu Natty with IcedTea (OpenJDK) it doesn't. It could well be down to the version of Java you have installed - try replacing OpenJDK with Sun's Java version.

To get Sun's Java you will need to make sure the Partner repository is enabled in Software Sources.

Comment: Well Im using OpenJRE and it is working fine.

Comment: Two years can make a lot of difference. :)